# Competing version of log4j in pom

Tags: java, spring, web-services, maven, logging

We are creating a webservice which hits existing business code. A required jar which deals with logging throughout the business layer is org.ops4j.pax.logging. I have include this in the pom.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>pax-logging-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This jar allows access to a particular log4j method which is used throughout the business layer.

```
LOGGER.debug(object, object);
```

We also wish to configure logging on the webservice in particular the use of appenders.
It would seem the methods required for dealing with these appenders are not available in pax-logging-api but are available in pax-logging-service.

However (and you can see where this is going) the initial logger method described above (and info, warn,.. etc methods like it) is available in pax-logging-api but is NOT available in pax-logging-service.

Whichever entry is included first in the pom file (pax-logging-api or pax-logging-service) is the jar from which the log4j instance is grabbed.

We **DEFINETELY** require pax-logging-api as the business code which uses this is non negotiable.

Has anyone any thoughts about how we can deal appenders which are part of the  pax-logging-service?

Comment: Just checked the two jars on the Maven repo and only pax-logging-service has a dependency on log4j.  Are you sure your conflict isn't coming from somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Jeremy.
I don't believe it is a matter of dependency.

Both pax-logging-api and pax-logging-service jars have org.apache.log4j packages which include a Logger.
One of these is the logger which will get used.
One has a debug method which takes two objects, one doesn't.
We need the one that has.

However we also need the other jar because it has all the Appender classes.

Comment: It seems to me that these jars are borked.  They should not both have identical classes with identical packages in them, especially as the service jar declares the api jar as a maven dependency.  You could try unpacking the service class, deleting the duplicated classes and repacking it.

Comment: Cheers for your comments Jeremy.
A colleague of mine has sorted the problem.

He created a hacked version of log4j to which he added the missing debug(object, object) methods.
He added the pax-logging-service as a dependency.
     **TADA**